# Why use torch.repeat in place of for loop while increasing the dimension in torch tensor?

Tags: pytorch, repeat

```py
one_hot_labels = get_one_hot_labels(labels.to(device), n_classes)

# note one_hot_labels is torch.Size([128, 10])

image_one_hot_labels = one_hot_labels[:, :, None, None]

image_one_hot_labels=image_one_hot_labels.repeat(1,1,mnist_shape[1],mnist_shape[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, using a pytorch function to perform something which could be done with a for loop is much faster than doing the loop. Their functions are optimized both for CPU and GPU to a point you cannot reach with raw python.

And it's cleaner : using `repeat` makes it a self-explanatory 1-line code, whereas using the for-loop makes the code lose clarity.

Final side note : if you can, use `expand` instead of `repeat`, the former is much more memory efficient since there it does not perform any copy (only changing the stride values to pretend it's bigger)